# user interaction windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to do my university project. We suppose to develop windows phone application that should track the user behavior and interaction with phone while driving.

At the moment we just trying to understand what we able to do and track.
we thought about monitoring maybe

- incoming call, incoming sms and afcourse if the user answered to those,
- maybe outgoing call
- headset plugged in/out
- click on any hardware button
- screen touching..

and all the interrupts made by the user.

What our options? Can someone refer me to relevant reading?

Answer (score 0):

for the purpose of your app, I suggest you implement something with voice control so that the driver can interact with his windows phone without  having to touch it.
Visit these links for more info: 
Here's [the first link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp7/basics/use-speech-on-my-phone/)
Here's [the second link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/)